# Cannot find module portfinder - latest AngularCLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've recently re-installed AngularCLI to the latest version, however when I use `ng n MyNewProject` I get the following error message in the terminal `Cannot find module 'portfinder'` now I've googled this and many solutions stated do this:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean 
npm install -g angular-cli@webpack
```

Now I've done this but still have the same issue, `Cannot find module 'portfinder'`

Can any suggest what else to try?

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer html-webpack-plugin@2.22.0 wants webpack@*
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-webpack@1.8.0 wants webpack@^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer sass-loader@3.2.3 wants webpack@^1.12.6 || ^2.1.0-beta
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer string-replace-loader@1.0.5 wants webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.0.0-beta || ^2.1.0-beta
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-server@2.1.0-beta.3 wants webpack@^2.1.0-beta
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular CLI needs some prerequisites, one of those is npm version 3xxx. 
I can see npm v2.15.8 in the errors list.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#prerequisites

See if you uninstall Angular Cli and update npm, it will be fixed or not.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean 

npm install npm -g
npm install -g angular-cli
```

Answer (score 4):

Yah, I have got the same error, I solved it by installing 'portfinder'

Command:

```
npm install portfinder
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by following the video on nodejs official site (fixing name permissions).

On mac os X El.., the main problem was a rights\permissions issue (please change muyiwaishola to your_user_name and past the lines below into the terminal;

```
sudo chown -R muyiwaishola /usr/local/
sudo chown -R muyiwaishola /usr/local/bin/
sudo chown -R muyiwaishola /usr/local/share/
sudo chown -R muyiwaishola /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

if the node modules path has been altered from default, you may also check on the website as suggested.